# How to build newtworkx graph with numpy matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, networkx

I m trying to build view of graph which is given like numpy matrix of adjency.
For example,

```
matrix=[['1' '0' '0'], ['0' '1' '0'], ['0' '0' '1']]

matrix = np.array(matrix)

f = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4))
a = f.add_subplot(111)
plt.axis('off')

G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(matrix)
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, ax=a)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
```

Gives me full graph always for all the matrixes I enter. What is incorrect here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code with a few bits filled in:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline  
#%matplotlib notebook

matrix=np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0,1]])
f = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4))
a = f.add_subplot(111)
plt.axis('off')

G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(matrix)
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, ax=a)
```

Returns:

[image]

Which I'm guessing is what you're after.

Comment: Inserted your code to my,still the same problem. Here is new code in question.

Comment: Your matrix needs commas between items, and the 0's and 1's need to be integers, not strings.